# Keep FFMPEG encoding session running

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, centos

I am trying to encode an external HLS (m3u8) link into MPEG-TS over UDP via ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://example.com/index400.m3u8 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000?pkt_size=1316
```

Currently I am executing the command directly inside a terminal which I keep open on my Centos server. However, and after some time (volatile), I get the following error :

> Failed to resolve hostname example.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
>   [hls,applehttp @ 0x349b420] Failed to reload playlist 0

My question is, how can I run this command in a bash script or upstart or … so that whenever it unexpectedly stops, it automatically restarts.
I prefer not to use third parties like monit, and please be explicit in writing the script with annotation for newbies, I am not well experienced on this.

Comment: why not use an infintite loop? `while true ; do ffmpeg ....  ; done` . This will run cmd, and only restart when the cmd quits or fails. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out to be simpler than I thought. For future reference, this is what I did, in a terminal:

Create a new script:

```sh
vi test.sh
```

Insert the following code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  echo `ffmpeg -re -i http://example.com/index400.m3u8 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000?pkt_size=1316`
done
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.

Execute the following commands:

```sh
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh
```

And voilà, `ffmpeg` will automatically restart when an error occurs.

Comment: you don't need the `echo ` with cmd-substitution, just run `ffmpeg`, right? Good luck.